# If I create an interface for data returned from an API. How can I handle the possibility that it might be changed?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn typescript with a simple weather webpage that returns data from the OpenWeather API. I've set up an interface to handle the data object that is returned.

My question is, if they decided to change the name of a property in that object, how do I catch that without using type any?

```
interface responseData {

   name: string;
   main: {
       temp: number;
       pressure: number;
       humidity: number;
   }
   sys: {
       country: string;
       sunrise: number
       sunset: number
   }
   weather: {
       0: {
           description: string;
           id: number;
           icon: string;
       }
   }
}

console.log(response.main.temp);
```

As of right now the console.log() works and logs what is expected. However if OpenWeather decided to change "main" to "stats". How would I account for that?

Comment: There's no good way to handle this. But companies that provide APIs generally don't change them in this way, precisely because doing so would break code that depends on those APIs. And if they do need to make such a breaking change, they will either communicate this well beforehand, or make an entirely new version of the API. So this isn't really something you should worry about.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee.

First, TypeScript doesn't do anything in runtime, so, that will not help with this issue.
Also the issue itself is both rare and hard to avoid.

Usually public API providers make changes in newer versions of the API, which require different URLs or different sent/received headers, etc.

If a property is missing, there's not much you can do really. You cannot just "guess" what property replaced it in the code. All you can do is look for the things you need, and display an error message if it's not found (or hide the related feature silently, depending on the scenario).

If you don't trust this API provider, you can mark all the properties as optional (add `?` to each property name), so that in your code you remember to check them manually, and then it's up to your code to check them for values, and act if the values are missing.